# Preposition usage for "wage a war"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference in the meaning of the following two sentences:

> > Iran waged a war on Iraq.
> >
> > Iran waged a war with Iraq.

As per the definition of [wage](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wage), wage means "carry on". I checked the sample sentences on Oxford and found that "waged a war on" is only used in the examples mentioned here. However, I checked "waged a war with" on [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wage%20a%20war%20with%2C%20wage%20a%20war%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwage%20a%20war%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwage%20a%20war%20on%3B%2Cc0) and found that this combination is also used. Is it a  mistake in the usage of the preposition or it has any other meaning?

Comment: You can use either preposition with "waged war".  Saying "Iran waged a war **on** Iraq" has a connotation that Iran is the aggressor and Iraq is the defender, while the pronoun **with** is more neutral as to who might be "at fault" for starting the war.

Answer (score 1):

The expressions "... waged war on ...", "waged war with ..." or " ... waged war against ..." are used to name  the enemy.

The expression " ... waged war with ..." also can be  used to describe now the war was waged.  For example: "They waged war with artillery and cavalry charges." or "They waged war with great ferocity."